# How to make the end-of-proof symbol (the square on the far right) thicker (or bolder) than it actually is

Tags: symbols, proof-package

My question is: how to make the square on the right at the end of the proof in the `proof` environment thicker or bolder ?!.

I guess that we have to use the command `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{something}`. But what must be put in the last parentheses?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can experiment with different thickness. Here's a modified definition of `\openbox` that uses a parameter `\openboxthickness`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% amsthm.sty, line 422:
%\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
%  \hbox to.77778em{%
%  \hfil\vrule
%  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
%  \vrule\hfil}}
\newcommand{\openboxthickness}{0.4pt} % default
\renewcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
    \hfil\vrule width \openboxthickness
    \vbox to.675em{%
      \hrule width \dimexpr.675em-2\dimexpr\openboxthickness height \openboxthickness
      \vfil
      \hrule height\openboxthickness
    }%
    \vrule width \openboxthickness
    \hfil
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This has the standard.
\end{proof}

\renewcommand{\openboxthickness}{1pt}

\begin{proof}
This has 1pt.
\end{proof}

\renewcommand{\openboxthickness}{1.5pt}

\begin{proof}
This has 1.5pt.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, because you said "thicker" and "bolder",
you maybe meant a square that's roughly the same size of `\qedsymbol`,
but made up of thicker lines.

If that's the case, scaling or resizing the character won't help;
as far as I know you can't directly interact with the strokes of a glyph because TeX sees all of them as a single box.

But because core TeX can draw rectangular blobs of ink and
`\qedsymbol` is simply 4 rectangles, we can use TeX rules to draw a square of side `\qedside` using some length `\qedthickness` as the, well, thickness of four rules.
See @egreg's answer for this case.

**--EDIT--**
(this is my previous answer, which addresses the case where you just want an overall smaller or larger `\qedsymbol`)

You can use `\scalebox` from `graphicx` to scale `\qedsymbol` for a certain factor, or
use `\resizebox{...}{!}` (from the same package) to make it have a certain width
(or `\resizebox{!}{...}` to make it have a certain height.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewCommandCopy\oldqedsymbol\qedsymbol
% choose _one_ of the following lines:
\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\scalebox{1.2}{\oldqedsymbol}}
\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\resizebox{!}{2.3ex}{\oldqedsymbol}}
\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\resizebox{2em}{!}{\oldqedsymbol}}
% 1.2 and 2.3ex and 2em are arbitrary sizes; choose whatever fits your needs

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  The original symbol and then the scaled one:\hfill\oldqedsymbol\qedhere
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```